# Extracting a bad prediction out but prediction didn't improve

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, predictive-models

I am predicting a time series $y$. I have a baseline prediction time series let's call it $x$. By baseline I just mean a prediction I will later improve on.

I did more research and found that I can systematically come up with another time series $z$ that have lower or even negative correlation with $y$. $z$ has a pretty significant standard deviation too (about 1/3 of $x$)

I thought $x - z$ would definitely have higher correlation with $y$ since I removed a significant low correlation part of my baseline prediction. Imagine time series $x = u+z$, if $z$ has lower correlation with $y$, I think intuitively $u$ should have higher correlation? So two components "balance out" when they add together.

But it doesn't.. what did I miss?

I guess another way to ask this question is, can $u+v$ have higher correlation with $y$ than both $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Your question lacks the information needed to understand and answer it.  Please explain what you mean by "baseline prediction," what $i$ means (what sense would it make to predict a value for a time $i$ when you already have an observation for that time?), how you compute correlation, what $z_i$ is intended to do for your prediction, and how you have determined the correlation between $x_i-z_i$ and $y_i.$

Comment: @whuber sorry rewarded. Removed subscripts to be more clear

Comment: @whuber added a more concise form of the question at the end

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times here, so let me just point out that abstractly if you start with any random variable $y$ and add some independent noise $e$ to it and set $u=y/2+e,$ $v=y/2-e,$ then (a) $u$ and $v$ will not be 100% correlated with $y$ but $u+v=y$ is 100% correlated with $y.$